# Fluent Assertions : How to check for key value pair with out case

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I have a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, object>` which I am trying assert with Fluent Assertions. I need to check if it contains a key called "iss" and value "ABC". I need to do assert the "value" field without considering the case. Is it supported?

Comment: is it a single dictionary item that has key 'iss' and value 'abc' or separate?

Comment: Yes, it's possible and not difficult. What code do you have so far?

Comment: it is a dictionary wich has one of the key as "iss" and value "abc"

Comment: payload.Should().Contain("iss", ValidIssuer); is what i have. I do not want use ValidIssuer.ToLower as I do not know what is going to be the case

Comment: @Shetty. did the answer help?

Answer (score 5):

```
dictionary.Should().ContainKey("iss").WhichValue.Should().BeEquivalentTo("abc");
```

Comment: .WhichValue.Should().BeEquivalentTo("abc") does not exists. and .WhichValue.Should().ShouldBeEquivalentTo("abc") does not work. It compares with case.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom assertion.. Something along these lines

```
 public static class GenericDictionaryAssertions
{
    public static void FirstKeyMatchesAndValueInvariantMatch<TKey, TValue>(this GenericDictionaryAssertions<TKey, TValue> assertions, TKey key, string value) where TKey : class
    {
        var someCondition = assertions.Subject.Any(a => a.Key == key && string.Equals(a.Value as string, value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        Execute.Assertion
           .ForCondition(someCondition)
           .BecauseOf("")
           .FailWith("Expected list to contain key " + key);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Normal()
    {
        var actual = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"iss", "abc"}};
        actual.Should().FirstKeyMatchesAndValueInvariantMatch("iss", "ABC");
    }
}
```

A little inelegant because of the ToString().. but should get you started

Comment: I am evaluating other options as well. I will accept the answer if I dont find a better solution

Comment: This does not work. assertions.Subject.Any(a => a.Key == key && string.Equals(a.Value as string, value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) returns false

Comment: @Shetty I just tried again and it returns true. I've update the code to show the full NUnit test fixture. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

So after learning various ways to look up a `KeyValuePair` (only to find out the data set itself was the issue), I found this is the simplest way to handle the lookup you're looking for with [FluentAssertions's Dictionaries](https://fluentassertions.com/dictionaries/).

```cs
dictionary.Should().Contain("iss", "ABC".ToLowerInvariant());
```